# CSS specificity or inheritance?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I've looked at similar questions here but I haven't found one particular to my case.

If I read this article correctly: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

then what is happening doesn't make sense to me.  Can someone explain if this is due to locality, inheritance or specificity please?  I've stripped out all the unrelated css.

CSS

```
a:link {font-size:0.875em;color:#005984}
.button {color:#fff}
```

HTML

```
<a class="button">Awesome call to action</a>
```

I end up with a button that has blue text, instead of white.  Now, a is an element, so it should have lower specificity than the .button class, should it not?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity): although `a` is an element type selector which is less specific than a class selector, it's accompanied by a `:link` pseudo-class which is equally specific to your `.button` class. A type + pseudo-class will therefore be more specific than a class.

There is no inheritance going on here as there are no parent element styles that I can see being applied to your element. [Inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#inheritance) refers to adopting styles from parent elements. When you see the link displaying blue instead of white, that's the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) at work, not inheritance.

Locality isn't a CSS term (at least not in its glossary), so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

If you need your call-to-action button to be white, simply give it the `a` selector as well, so your selectors are equally specific and the last declaration will take precedence:

```
a:link {font-size:0.875em;color:#005984}
a.button {color:#fff}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've heard people refer to how close an attribute is as "locality", so I just ripped off the term. Thank you for your response, I wasn't sure if the pseudo-class was additive.  Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>   - count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
>   - count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
>   - count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (= c)
>   - ignore the universal selector
>
> Selectors inside the negation pseudo-class are counted like any other, but the negation itself does not count as a pseudo-class.
>
> Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.

So:

> `a:link`
>   - a=0
>   - b=1
>   - c=1
>   - Result = 011
>
> `.button`
>   - a=0
>   - b=1
>   - c=0
>   - Result = 010
>
> **Result**: `a:link` is higher than `.button`.

Fix: `:link` won't work on anything but `a` tags anyway, so specifying `a:link` is redundant. Use `:link` instead, and that will fix the problem (provided `.button` is defined *after* `:link`)

Comment: Thank you for breaking this down even further, and the extra tip for :link!